# FTP List Files return always root files

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm using `apache.commons.net` `ftpClient` but I'm facing a problem that I'm not sure how to fix.

So basically I log in the server, set the passive mode, and then I run:

```
fileFTPFiles = this.ftpClient.listFiles(strPath);
```

In all the servers I have connected to until today, this worked like a charm but today I connected to a server that instead of returning the file or the files in the give path always returns the landing directory files...

Although if I run

```
fileFTPFiles = this.ftpClient.mlistDir(strPath);
```

it returns what I expect.

Can anyone explain me why this happens and if there is a easy way to detect whether to use `listFile` or `mlistFiles`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the local passive mode or remote? I had the same problem and I found some explanations on the FileZilla Documentation: https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration.

This happened to me because my ftp client was not able to bound the server's port returned by PORT ftp command(sent before every request). By the way, the `FTPCLient.setActivePortRange(min, max);` method don't take effect at all;

The easiest way to avoid this seems to create a raw socket to verify network bindness at the address.